# IOS pagehide not triggered. Cannot detecting page unload

Tags: javascript, ios, sendbeacon

I call this function when my page is loaded:

```
function setBeacon() {
if (!navigator.sendBeacon) {
    alert("No navigator beacon available. This is a critical bug which must be fixed.");
}
else
{
    if ('beforeunload' in window) {
        $(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
            generateFormSendBeacon();
            return undefined;
        });
    } else if ('onpagehide' in window) {
        alert("on page hide");
        window.addEventListener("pagehide", function() {
            generateFormSendBeacon();
            return undefined;
        });
    } else {
        alert("Neither beforeunload or onpagehide events are available. Please report this to John, with details about your browser.");
    }
}
```

This works perfectly on desktop. I am using navigator.sendBeacon in the generateFormSendBeacon() function. It sends it correctly (I have a breakpoint in my server receiving this). On mobile however, in both safari and chrome, the 'beforeunload' event doesn't exist. [But according to apple, we should use pagehide instead.](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006511-SW5) The 'on page hide' alert shows; iOS does have access to this event. However the event is never fired, as I never get to the breakpoint in my server. Again; testing the same code path on desktop, it works fine. How does one detect the page unloading on iOS?

Comment: Can confirm that on Safari for iOS 13.6.1 `pagehide` event is still not being triggered when clicking "X" on the tab. However, it is triggered when closing the tab by swiping. This is, presumably, a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Some browsers [ignore dialog prompts when unloading the page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Browser_compatibility). This is expected.

You’re probably running into [WebKit issue #193508](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=193508).